# Issue importing netCF4 with python 3.9

Tags: python, netcdf4

I'm trying to import netCDF4 and got this error message:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
```

> from netCDF4 import *   File
> "/home/username/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/netCDF4/**init**.py",
> line 3, in 
> from ._netCDF4 import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4._netCDF4'

I did not have this issue before upgrading to python3.9. I can't find answer to this anywhere else. Thank you in advance.